# Extracting data from a complex string value

Tags: javascript, next.js

```
{JSON.stringify(walletData.transactions, null, 2)}
```

I have been trying to access the backend data and wants to display it as a table. for that i have converted the response to below array by above command

```
[
  {
    "date": "Nov 07, 2023",
    "description": "You withdrew funds from your wallet.",
    "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '-10', 'display': '-10.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '10', 'display': '10.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "VICA {'token_symbol': 'VICA', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '5000', 'display': '5000.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "USDT {'token_symbol': 'USDT', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '150', 'display': '150.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 01, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '10', 'display': '10.000'}}"
  }
]
```

I have displayed the table by following code.

```
<TableContainer>
      <Table variant="simple">
        <Thead>
          <Tr>
            <Th>Date</Th>
            <Th>Coin</Th>
            <Th>Coin Amount</Th>
          </Tr>
        </Thead>
        <Tbody>
          {userWalletData.transactions.map((info) => {
            return (
              <Tr>
                <Td>{info.date}</Td>
                <Td>{info.amount}</Td>
                <Td>{info.date} </Td>
                <Td>{}</Td>
              </Tr>
            );
          })}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

What i want isto display only the coin and its transaction amount in the table. How to extract that data

Hi @fgkolf
This the raw data output by `console.log(userWalletData)`

```
{
    "wallet_address": "WALLET ADDRESS",
    "eth_balance": {
        "is_exact": true,
        "exact": "10",
        "display": "10.000"
    },
    "usdt_balance": {
        "is_exact": true,
        "exact": "150",
        "display": "150.000"
    },
    "vica_balance": {
        "is_exact": true,
        "exact": "5000",
        "display": "5000.000"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "date": "Nov 07, 2023",
            "description": "You withdrew funds from your wallet.",
            "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '-10', 'display': '-10.000'}}"
        },
        {
            "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
            "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
            "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '10', 'display': '10.000'}}"
        },
        {
            "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
            "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
            "amount": "VICA {'token_symbol': 'VICA', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '5000', 'display': '5000.000'}}"
        },
        {
            "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
            "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
            "amount": "USDT {'token_symbol': 'USDT', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '150', 'display': '150.000'}}"
        },
        {
            "date": "Nov 01, 2023",
            "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
            "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '10', 'display': '10.000'}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I want to know data structure.where is coin?

Comment: To which key(s) are you referring for "coin"?

Comment: What is the structure before stringify? Can you provide the raw `walletData.transactions`

Comment: If you have any control over how this data is formatted it would make it much easier on you if it was JSON. As it is it requires digging into `transactions[index].amount` and parsing it manually (best bet), with a regex (hardest), or converting it to JSON (second hardest) so JSON.parse can handle it. Normally okay with this stuff, but can't get this yet. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you wanted, but your JSON is broken. I have fixed your JSON and mined the data you wanted to mine in the snippet below, but I strongly advise you to fix your JSON, `'is_exact': True` is invalid JSON:

```js
let input = [
  {
    "date": "Nov 07, 2023",
    "description": "You withdrew funds from your wallet.",
    "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '-10', 'display': '-10.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '10', 'display': '10.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "VICA {'token_symbol': 'VICA', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '5000', 'display': '5000.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 05, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "USDT {'token_symbol': 'USDT', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '150', 'display': '150.000'}}"
  },
  {
    "date": "Nov 01, 2023",
    "description": "You deposited funds into your wallet.",
    "amount": "ETH {'token_symbol': 'ETH', 'amount': {'is_exact': True, 'exact': '10', 'display': '10.000'}}"
  }
]


console.log(input.map(item => JSON.parse(item.amount.substring(item.amount.indexOf(" ") + 1).replace("True,", "'True',").replace("False,", "'False',").replaceAll("'", '"'))).map(item => { return {token_symbol: item.token_symbol, display: item.amount.display}}))
```